# Regular expression for alphanumeric with atleast one digit

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match an alphanumeric string with at least one digit.
The second condition is that it's minimum length should be 3.

For example, the following strings should match

```
111
12345
ABCD1
123A
11AA11
```

And the following should not match

```
ABCD
AB
12
1A
```

I have got myself to a point where I can get the first condition right.
That is, having minimum one digit:

```
([a-zA-z0-9]*[0-9]+[a-zA-z0-9]*)
```

But I don't have any idea to specify a minimum length. If I try using {3},
it will require minimum of 3 numbers.

Comment: Which language are using?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this in javascript but I'm looking for a general regular expression

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex for alphanumeric string including at least one digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68622285/regex-for-alphanumeric-string-including-at-least-one-digit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [a positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to ascertain that there's at least one digit, and use `{3,}` to indicate that it should match at least 3 characters:

```
/^(?=.*\d)[a-z\d]{3,}$/i
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assure your expression contains a digit, and then match the minimum-three-chars:

```
/^(?=.*?\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}$/
```