# Regex for alphanumeric string including at least one digit

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex with at the conditions:

- a) minimum 13 alphanumeric characters
- b) maximum 17 alphanumeric
  characters
- c) and at least 1 digit.

This regex fulfils a) and b). How can it fulfil also condition c)?

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{13,17}$
```

Example input texts:

```
# matching
123456789abcd
123456789abcdef
123456789abcdefg

# no match: too long
123456789abcdefgef

# no match: no digit
abcdefghijklmno

# no match: not alphanumeric only
123456789@abcdefg
```

The flavor is Java 8.

Comment: I would also benchmark 2 separate regexes combined. The one you have for a) and b) and a simple one that checks for that at least one digit. It might be faster than a single, more complicated regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to make a password checker.  I suggest that you NOT try to do it all in one single regex.

Check your input against two different regexes that must both match:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{13,17}$        # 13-17 alphanumerics
```

and

```
[0-9]                       # at least one digit
```

Compared to this suggestion from another answer...

```
^(?=[a-zA-Z]*[0-9])(?=[0-9]*[a-zA-Z])[[:alnum:]]{13,17}$
```

... it's so much clearer that way, and easier to change when your rules change in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Regex:

```regex
^(?=[a-zA-Z]*[0-9])(?=[0-9]*[a-zA-Z])[[:alnum:]]{13,17}$
```

Explanation:
`^(?=[a-zA-Z]*[0-9])` - Lookahead for zero or more letters followed by a number, somewhere in the string, note this is faster than the `(?=.*[0-9])` suggested in another answer.

`(?=[0-9]*[a-zA-Z])` - as above but looking for at least one letter (I assume you want this, although it wasn't specified in your answer.

`[[:alnum:]]{13,17}$` - The actual match bit; this is just your regex (`[a-zA-Z0-9]{13,17}$`) in short-hand.

If it's more likely that a string will *not* have a letter then swapping the order of the lookaheads should make it faster. The current order would be best if a missing number is the most likely fail condition (as the regex will fail faster).

See https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#password for a detailed explanation.

[Regex Tests](https://regex101.com/r/XfgXOS/1)